# Caching ASP.NET - cache vary-by-user="true" vary-by-route="id" can somebody explain this how this combination would work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, caching

-can somebody explain this how this combination would work?
I understand how each is working, but am not sure how it would work if those are combined?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any number of different parameters, and the cache tag assistant will construct a key combination. The following is an example of caching tags, which will cache different results for each user and *id* route parameter:

```
  <cache vary-by-route="id" vary-by-user="true">
    Current Time Inside Cache Tag Helper: @DateTime.Now
</cache>
```

Result:

[image]

**Official instructions:**

> vary-by-user specifies whether or not the cache resets when the
> signed-in user (or Context Principal) changes. The current user is
> also known as the Request Context Principal and can be viewed in a
> Razor view by referencing @User.Identity.Name.
>
> Using this attribute maintains the contents in cache through a sign-in
> and sign-out cycle. When the value is set to true, an authentication
> cycle invalidates the cache for the authenticated user. The cache is
> invalidated because a new unique cookie value is generated when a user
> is authenticated. Cache is maintained for the anonymous state when no
> cookie is present or the cookie has expired. If the user is not
> authenticated, the cache is maintained

.